# Conditionals in release management 2013

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I am exploring Release Management 2013 from the continuous deployment point of view. While creating release template and adding actions I came across some scenarios and have queries on the same.

1) Can I add conditions such as if-else style to the deployment sequence while creating a workflow for release template? I have not seen any default action for this.

2) Can I get the return value/code of a process/action and based on it perform the suitable action for subsequent action in the flow or use it as an argument in subsequent flow?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the program manager for VSTS Release Management. My recommendation is to use the new Release Management capabilities in TFS 2015 U2 or Visual Studio Team Services feature.

It supports both your asks #1 conditionals on steps and #2. ability to set output variables and consume them in downstream tasks.

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/

Comment: Agree that new release management has all the features, but my client wants to stick with release management 2013 only, Could you suggest what can be done to with the older version only?

Comment: @MukulKazla You could write the entire deployment process yourself in a PowerShell script. A better solution is to migrate off of Release Management Server; the native version in TFS 2015+ requires less maintenance (there's no separate install), is far more powerful, and receives feature updates regularly. The old RM server is no longer being updated with new features.